# Using Electronic Health Records to predict future diagnosis codes with Gated Recurrent Units - (Error: Sample larger than population or is negative)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, time-series, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on clinical EHR.
I am currently referring to this blog and github link here.

https://sparklerussell.com/post/using-electronic-health-records-to-predict-future-diagnosis-codes-with-gated-recurrent-units/
https://github.com/sparalic/Electronic-Health-Records-GRUs

I have generated the dataset and processed it as per the instructions in the notebooks present in the repository. I am facing an issue trying to train the model.

using : jupytor notebook (with google colab)

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pack_padded_sequence, pad_packed_sequence
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np
import itertools
import pickle
import sys, random
```

---

Load Data :

```
def load_data(sequences, labels):
            dataSize = len(labels)
            idx = np.random.permutation(dataSize)
            nTest = int(np.ceil(0.15 * dataSize))
            nValid = int(np.ceil(0.10 * dataSize))
            test_idx = idx[:nTest]
            valid_idx = idx[nTest:nTest+nValid]
            train_idx = idx[nTest+nValid:]
            
            train_x = sequences[train_idx]
            train_y = labels[train_idx]
            test_x = sequences[test_idx]
            test_y = labels[test_idx]
            valid_x = sequences[valid_idx]
            valid_y = labels[valid_idx]

            train_x = [sorted(seq) for seq in train_x]
            train_y = [sorted(seq) for seq in train_y]
            valid_x = [sorted(seq) for seq in valid_x]
            valid_y = [sorted(seq) for seq in valid_y]
            test_x = [sorted(seq) for seq in test_x]
            test_y = [sorted(seq) for seq in test_y]

            train = (train_x, train_y)
            test = (test_x, test_y)
            valid = (valid_x, valid_y)
            return (train, test, valid)
```

Padding the input :

```
def padding(seqs, labels, vocab, n_classes):
    lengths = np.array([len(seq) for seq in seqs]) - 1 # remove the last list in each patient's sequences for labels
    n_samples = len(lengths)
    maxlen = np.max(lengths)

    x = torch.zeros(maxlen, n_samples, vocab) # maxlen = number of visits, n_samples = samples
    y = torch.zeros(maxlen, n_samples, n_classes)
    mask = torch.zeros(maxlen, n_samples)
    for idx, (seq,label) in enumerate(zip(seqs,labels)):
        for xvec, subseq in zip(x[:,idx,:], seq[:-1]):
            xvec[subseq] = 1.
        for yvec, subseq in zip(y[:,idx,:], label[1:]):
            yvec[subseq] = 1.
        mask[:lengths[idx], idx] = 1.
        
    return x, y, lengths, mask
```

GRU Class :

```
torch.manual_seed(1)
class EHRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inputDimSize, hiddenDimSize,embSize, batchSize, numClass):
        super(EHRNN, self).__init__()

    self.hiddenDimSize = hiddenDimSize
    self.inputDimSize = inputDimSize
    self.embSize = embSize
    self.numClass = numClass
    self.batchSize = batchSize

    #Initialize random weights
    self.W_z = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.embSize, self.hiddenDimSize).cuda())
    self.W_r = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.embSize, self.hiddenDimSize).cuda())
    self.W_h = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.embSize, self.hiddenDimSize).cuda())

    self.U_z = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.hiddenDimSize, self.hiddenDimSize).cuda())
    self.U_r = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.hiddenDimSize, self.hiddenDimSize).cuda())
    self.U_h = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.hiddenDimSize, self.hiddenDimSize).cuda())

    self.b_z = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(self.hiddenDimSize).cuda())
    self.b_r = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(self.hiddenDimSize).cuda())
    self.b_h = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(self.hiddenDimSize).cuda())

    
    self.params = [self.W_z, self.W_r, self.W_h, 
                   self.U_z, self.U_r, self.U_h,
                   self.b_z, self.b_r, self.b_h]

    
def forward(self,emb,h):
    z = torch.sigmoid(torch.matmul(emb, self.W_z)  + torch.matmul(h, self.U_z) + self.b_z)
    r = torch.sigmoid(torch.matmul(emb, self.W_r)  + torch.matmul(h, self.U_r) + self.b_r)
    h_tilde = torch.tanh(torch.matmul(emb, self.W_h)  + torch.matmul(r * h, self.U_h) + self.b_h)
    h = z * h + ((1. - z) * h_tilde)
    return h

                       
def init_hidden(self):
    return Variable(torch.zeros(self.batchSize,self.hiddenDimSize))
```

Custom Layer for handling two layer GRU :

```
torch.manual_seed(1)
class build_EHRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inputDimSize=4894, hiddenDimSize=[200,200], batchSize=100, embSize=200,numClass=4894, dropout=0.5,logEps=1e-8):
        super(build_EHRNN, self).__init__()
    
    self.inputDimSize = inputDimSize
    self.hiddenDimSize = hiddenDimSize
    self.numClass = numClass
    self.embSize = embSize
    self.batchSize = batchSize
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
    self.logEps = logEps
    
    
    # Embedding inputs
    self.W_emb = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.inputDimSize, self.embSize).cuda())
    self.b_emb = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(self.embSize).cuda())
    
    self.W_out = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(self.hiddenDimSize, self.numClass).cuda())
    self.b_out = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(self.numClass).cuda())
     
    self.params = [self.W_emb, self.W_out, 
                   self.b_emb, self.b_out] 

def forward(self,x, y, lengths, mask):
    self.emb = torch.tanh(torch.matmul(x, self.W_emb) + self.b_emb)
    input_values = self.emb
    self.outputs = [input_values]
    for i, hiddenSize in enumerate([self.hiddenDimSize, self.hiddenDimSize]):  # iterate over layers
        rnn = EHRNN(self.inputDimSize,hiddenSize,self.embSize,self.batchSize,self.numClass) # calculate hidden states
        hidden_state = []
        h = self.init_hidden().cuda()
        for i,seq in enumerate(input_values): # loop over sequences in each batch
            h = rnn(seq, h)                    
            hidden_state.append(h)    
        hidden_state = self.dropout(torch.stack(hidden_state))    # apply dropout between layers
        input_values = hidden_state
   
    y_linear = torch.matmul(hidden_state, self.W_out)  + self.b_out # fully connected layer
    yhat = F.softmax(y_linear, dim=1)  # yhat
    yhat = yhat*mask[:,:,None]   # apply mask
    
    # Loss calculation
    cross_entropy = -(y * torch.log(yhat + self.logEps) + (1. - y) * torch.log(1. - yhat + self.logEps))
    last_step = -torch.mean(y[-1] * torch.log(yhat[-1] + self.logEps) + (1. - y[-1]) * torch.log(1. - yhat[-1] + self.logEps))
    prediction_loss = torch.sum(torch.sum(cross_entropy, dim=0),dim=1)/ torch.cuda.FloatTensor(lengths)
    cost = torch.mean(prediction_loss) + 0.000001 * (self.W_out ** 2).sum() # regularize
    return (yhat, hidden_state, cost)

def init_hidden(self):
    return torch.zeros(self.batchSize, self.hiddenDimSize)  # initial state
```

Load data :

```
train, test, valid = load_data(sequences, labels)
```

Batch Size:

```
batchSize = 100
n_batches = int(np.ceil(float(len(train[0])) / float(batchSize)))-1
n_batches_valid = int(np.ceil(float(len(valid[0])) / float(batchSize)))-1
```

Model:

```
model = build_EHRNN(inputDimSize=4894, hiddenDimSize=200, batchSize=20, embSize=200, numClass=4894, dropout=0.5, logEps=1e-8)
model = model.to(device)

optimizer = torch.optim.Adadelta(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01, rho=0.90)
max_epochs = 5

loss_all = []
iteration = 0
        
for e in range(max_epochs):
for index in random.sample(range(n_batches), n_batches):
    batchX = train[0][:n_batches*batchSize][index*batchSize:(index+1)*batchSize]
    batchY = train[1][:n_batches*batchSize][index*batchSize:(index+1)*batchSize]
    
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    x, y, lengths, mask = padding(batchX, batchY, 4894, 4894)
    
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        x, y, lenghts, mask = x.cuda(), y.cuda(), lengths, mask.cuda()
    
    outputs, hidden, cost = model(x,y, h, lengths, mask)
    
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        cost.cuda()
    cost.backward()
    nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 5)
    optimizer.step()
    
    loss_all.append(cost.item())
    iteration +=1
    if iteration % 10 == 0:
        # Calculate Accuracy         
        losses = []
        model.eval()
        val_loss = []
        for index in random.sample(range(n_batches_valid), n_batches_valid):
            validX = valid[0][:n_batches_valid*batchSize][index*batchSize:(index+1)*batchSize]
            validY = valid[1][:n_batches_valid*batchSize][index*batchSize:(index+1)*batchSize]
            x, y, lengths, mask = padding(validX, validY, 4894, 4894)
            if torch.cuda.is_available():
                x, y, lenghts, mask = x.cuda(), y.cuda(), lenghts, mask.cuda()
            outputs, hidden_val, cost_val = model(x,y, h, lengths, mask)
            losses.append(cost_val)

        model.train()
        print("Epoch: {}/{}...".format(e+1, max_epochs),
                      "Step: {}...".format(iteration),
                      "Training Loss: {:.4f}...".format(np.mean(loss_all)),
                      "Val Loss: {:.4f}".format(torch.mean(torch.tensor(losses))))
```

ERROR :

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-9ca4916456a9> in <module>()
      8 
      9 for e in range(max_epochs):
---> 10     for index in random.sample(range(n_batches), n_batches):
     11         batchX = train[0][:n_batches*batchSize][index*batchSize:(index+1)*batchSize]
     12         batchY = train[1][:n_batches*batchSize][index*batchSize:(index+1)*batchSize]

/usr/lib/python3.7/random.py in sample(self, population, k)
    319         n = len(population)
    320         if not 0 <= k <= n:
--> 321             raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
    322         result = [None] * k
    323         setsize = 21        # size of a small set minus size of an empty list

ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative
```

I tried many things but I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Where have you defined `n_batches`?

Comment: I added n_batches code. batchSize = 100
n_batches = int(np.ceil(float(len(train[0])) / float(batchSize)))-1
n_batches_valid = int(np.ceil(float(len(valid[0])) / float(batchSize)))-1